How to resolve Third-Party Login Failure
I am having trouble using Github as third party for logging in to an app.
I am getting this error (page):
Third-Party Login Failure An error occurred while attempting to login via your third-party account.
My alluth version:
django-allauth==65.2.0

Project's settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # third-party apps
    "allauth_ui",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.github",
    "widget_tweaks",
    "slippers",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR/"templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                # allauth needs this from django
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "github": {
        "VERIFIED_EMAIL": True
    }
}

All settings in django admin's social application's entry are properly setup (i.e. Client ID and Secret Key). All matching correctly what was setup when creating the Github Apps...

Look at the example: https://docs.allauth.org/en/dev/installation/quickstart.html
Did you update the middleware section? "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware".
Another reason could be cause of Github ist using 2FA now.

Hi @BernhardBeatus, I have followed the documentation up to the letter.

I had updated the post to also show config for middleware and templates
